# save Unicode characters(utf-8) in oracle APEX with hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate

I use SQL Developer IDE to work visually with database, and hibernate_4.2.1 to save my data(in UTF-8 Unicode) to database in my application.

And problem is:

when i insert data from SQL Developer is fine, and show correct.

but when i insert from application it's don't show correct.

from SQL Developer:

```
INSERT INTO PLACEMENT_USER (ID, FIRST_NAME, last_name)
values(11111,'علی','علی پور');
```

![First record inserted from application with hibernate, 
 second record inserted from SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hzqO.jpg)

Comment: Check this post http://www.mularien.com/blog/2007/12/11/solving-problems-with-international-utf-8-data-using-hibernate-oracle-and-tomcat/

Comment: I trace my code and find that when a form submitted, i get none unicode form field data in my action

Answer (score 0):

Insert in your hibernate config  (that name is usually  hibernate.cfg.xml)  below code:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</property>
```